# how to setup Hadoop multinode environment?

Tags: hadoop2

I want to create Hadoop multinode Environment. I have 3 Ubuntu systems, one will b master and another 2 will be the slave. Have I to configure Hadoop in all 3 nodes?
Later on, if I want to add components like HIVE, Spark or HBase, do i need to configure these components on all 3 nodes?

Comment: yeah,you  have to install all this components in all node.
Later you have to configure those components based on you requirement (master or salve or worker or client) in respective conf. file

Answer (score 0):

Following the official docs
[Hadoop Cluster Setup](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.4/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/ClusterSetup.html#Configuring_Environment_of_Hadoop_Daemons)